# select dropdown menu values are overlapping dropdown in IE, working fine in firefox/chrome

Tags: css

This is my html code, when i click on dropdown values are overlapping dropdown menu instead of coming below the dropdown.

```
<th class="col-xs-1 subheader-table-color" style="width: 12.33% !important;">
                                     <span style="float: left; width: 40px;">
                                <select ng-model="filters.projectAgeOperator" style="border-radius: 4px !important;" class="select-WidHeight ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid dropdown ng-empty" uib-dropdown="">
                                 <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="eq">=</option>
                                        <option value="lt">&lt;</option>
                                        <option value="gt">&gt;</option>
                                </select>
                                </span>
                                <span style="float: left; width: 67px;margin-left: 7px;"><input class="filters form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-pattern" id="inputAge" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="filters.projectAge" style="width: 69px !important;" type="text"></span>
                                <br>

                                <p class="help-txt-table col-sm-12 noPad ng-hide" ng-show="dashboardData.userPreferences.showHelpTextEnabled" ng-class="{'no-display': !settingsForm.helpTxtOn}" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">Filter by age</p> 
                            </th>
```

Comment: Yes, because IE is prehistoric and not supported by almost anything - [Read here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/) about suppored browsers

Comment: it is not a issue its default browser functionality , if you need proper drop down in all browser i suggest you to use select2 jquery

Comment: there is no way to fix it?

Comment: use select 2 jQuery if you want to same show in all browser

Comment: Please add full code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with Bootstrap (by looking on used classes I assume you are using one) so people can actually test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example

```js
  $("select").select2({
 placeholder: "",
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.3/select2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.3/select2.css">
<th class="col-xs-1 subheader-table-color" style="width: 12.33% !important;">
                                     <span style="float: left; width: 40px;">
                                <select ng-model="filters.projectAgeOperator" style="border-radius: 4px !important;" class="select-WidHeight ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid dropdown ng-empty" uib-dropdown="">
                                 <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="eq">=</option>
                                        <option value="lt">&lt;</option>
                                        <option value="gt">&gt;</option>
                                </select>
                                </span>
                                <span style="float: left; width: 67px;margin-left: 7px;"><input class="filters form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-pattern" id="inputAge" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="filters.projectAge" style="width: 69px !important;" type="text"></span>
                                <br>
Please check below example 
                                <p class="help-txt-table col-sm-12 noPad ng-hide" ng-show="dashboardData.userPreferences.showHelpTextEnabled" ng-class="{'no-display': !settingsForm.helpTxtOn}" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">Filter by age</p> 
                            </th>
```

Comment: I used same example but its still not using jquery select2.with angular.js should I need to do something else to use jquery select2.